# Alert on jquery Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I make a function that runs each time an AJAX request is made ?

This is the function:

```
function Exec() {
    alert(1);
}
```

**Update:** The AJAX requests are made by other scripts I don't need to modify!

Comment: You can call this function in the success part of the response .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){                               
  alert(1);
});
```

Comment: +1 I hope it's only for testing purpose. Because it's far from user friendly.

Comment: In fact, I find it pretty user friendly, as you can control different phases of a ajax request, seperately. However I am not calling the other methods, not user friendly.

Comment: This instantiates a new `jQuery` object for `$(document)` while it isn’t needed. It’s better to use `$.ajaxSetup`, as explained in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389682/alert-on-jquery-ajax-request/5389713#5389713

Comment: @Mathias, not that I dont agree with you on your point, but, there is rarely a case where `$(document)` object is not instantiated, while we are using jQuery. So, it might not make such a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

TRY [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

```
$.ajax({
            url:'',
            data: {  },
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(1);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
            sucess: function (d) {
                 alert(d);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For example, if you use JQuery, you can do this using the following code:

```
$.ajax('script/to/load', function (data) { alert('AJAX request made!'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can
Using Jquery:

```
function Exec() { alert(1); }
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: Exec
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To run a function upon completing an Ajax request, you can use the `complete` option:

```
function Exec() {
  alert(1);
}

$.ajax('some-url.html',
  {
    complete: Exec
  }
);
```

…or, inline:

```
$.ajax('some-url.html',
  {
    complete: function() {
      alert(1);
    }
  }
);
```

To make this the default for all Ajax requests, you can use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function() {
    alert(1);
  }
});
```

Comment: "on ajax request" (on start) is not eq to complete. beforeSend is the correct answer as stated by diEcho